# Python if statement: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following Python code

```
def reward_function(params):
        import math
        # Read input variables
        waypoints = params['waypoints']
        closest_waypoints = params['closest_waypoints']
        heading = params['heading']
        # Initialize the reward with typical value 
        reward = 1.0
        # Calculate the direction of the center line based on the closest waypoints
        next_point = waypoints[closest_waypoints[1]]
        prev_point = waypoints[closest_waypoints[0]]
        # Calculate the direction in radius, arctan2(dy, dx), the result is (-pi, pi) in radians
        track_direction = math.atan2(next_point[1] - prev_point[1], next_point[0] - prev_point[0]) 
        # Convert to degree
        track_direction = math.degrees(track_direction)
        # Calculate the difference between the track direction and the heading direction of the car
        direction_diff = abs(track_direction - heading)
    if direction_diff > 180: # This line gives me the ERROR
        direction_diff = 360 - direction_diff
        # Penalize the reward if the difference is too large
        DIRECTION_THRESHOLD = 10.0
        if direction_diff > DIRECTION_THRESHOLD:
        reward *= 0.5
        return reward
```

I have tried a few different editors, but unable to fix this indentation issue. Any pointers are very welcome.

Comment: tabs and spaces folks, don't mix them

Comment: the `reward *= 0.5` lines is not indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use 8 spaces (2 tabs), use 4 (1 tab):

```
def reward_function(params):
    import math
    # Read input variables
    waypoints = params['waypoints']
    closest_waypoints = params['closest_waypoints']
    heading = params['heading']
    # Initialize the reward with typical value 
    reward = 1.0
    # Calculate the direction of the center line based on the closest waypoints
    next_point = waypoints[closest_waypoints[1]]
    prev_point = waypoints[closest_waypoints[0]]
    # Calculate the direction in radius, arctan2(dy, dx), the result is (-pi, pi) in radians
    track_direction = math.atan2(next_point[1] - prev_point[1], next_point[0] - prev_point[0]) 
    # Convert to degree
    track_direction = math.degrees(track_direction)
    # Calculate the difference between the track direction and the heading direction of the car
    direction_diff = abs(track_direction - heading)
    if direction_diff > 180: # This line gives me the ERROR
        direction_diff = 360 - direction_diff
        # Penalize the reward if the difference is too large
        DIRECTION_THRESHOLD = 10.0
        if direction_diff > DIRECTION_THRESHOLD:
            reward *= 0.5
            return reward
```

Comment: sure pep8 says use 4 spaces, but using 8 won't result in an error, it's not their issue here

Comment: Unless all of them are 8. OP is mixing 8 and 4

Comment: @BlackThunder It still giving indentation error on in line #19 `direction_diff = 360 - direction_diff